# pytest create object which is tightly coupling with anther config class?

Tags: python, pytest

I need to write tests for the following file.

**file1.py**

```
from other import Resource

class _Config:
    # ...omit...

    @classmethod
    def get_config(cls, p1=..., p2=..., p3=..., ...):
        return _Config(p1, p2, p3, ..)

def resource(name):
    # ....
    if name = '...':
        return Resource(_Config.get_config())
```

How to write a pytest fixture for resource?

```
from ..dir import file1

@pytest.fixture()
def value_resource():
    config = file1._Config(....)  # how to make the following statement to use config?
    return file1.resource('value1')
```

Comment: change the signature to `def resource(name, config=None): (...) return Resource(config or _Config.get_config())` and pass the `config` you want there?

Comment: Yes, changing the signature should work. However, I cannot change the code because it's others' code.

Comment: mock/monkeypatch the `get_config()` method to return your config then